# Merging list of dictionaries into a smaller list of dictionaries dependent on recurring values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, merge

I have a question regarding a list of dictionaries. Let me demonstrate my problem. Here is a sample list of dictionaries:

```
[{'a' : '1'}, {'b' : 'something'}, {'c' : 'else'},
 {'a' : '2'}, {'b' : 'anything'}, {'c' : 'if'},
 {'a' : '3'}, {'b' : 'nothing'}, {'c' : 'matters'}]
```

As you can see I have separated dictionaries, however I want to merge them. The condition is that when the dictionary name reoccurs, that should be a separate dictionary. Something like this:

```
list_of_dict = 
[{'a' : '1', 'b' : 'something', 'c' : 'else'},
 {'a' : '2', 'b' : 'anything', 'c' : 'if'},
 {'a' : '3', 'b' : 'nothing', 'c' : 'matters'}]
```

I have been trying to use `dict(ChainMap(*list_of_dict)`, however that will only return:

```
{'c': 'else', 'b': 'something', 'a': '1'}
```

I was thinking of maybe using a for loop to solve my problem, but I don't know how to start. Do you guys have any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be done with a for-loop, iterating over `list_of_dict` and checking if the key from the dictionary is in the latest dictionary in the return list. If not, append it to the latest dictionary using the `**` operator to merge the dictionaries, otherwise start a new dictionary in the return list.

**Code:**

```
list_of_dict = [{'a' : '1'}, {'b' : 'something'}, {'c' : 'else'},
                {'a' : '2'}, {'b' : 'anything'}, {'c' : 'if'},
                {'a' : '3'}, {'b' : 'nothing'}, {'c' : 'matters'}]

rv = [{}]

for d in list_of_dict:
    if list(d)[0] not in rv[-1]:
        rv[-1] = {**rv[-1], **d}
    else:
        rv.append(d)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> rv
[{'a': '1', 'b': 'something', 'c': 'else'},
 {'a': '2', 'b': 'anything', 'c': 'if'},
 {'a': '3', 'b': 'nothing', 'c': 'matters'}]
```

Comment: Do you think this can be done using list and dict comprehension?